# Is it possible to apply CSS styles to a sticky element when scrolling without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, animation, sticky

If I have a navigation bar which is set `postion:sticky;` in CSS, I'd like to add more style to it when it is "sticking" to the top of the container. In essence, the following code reproduce what I'd like as behavior, however I wanted to know if the same is possible *only* with CSS.

```js
const minScroll = $('.navbar').position().top;

$('.container').on('scroll', e => {
  let y = e.target.scrollTop;

  if (y > minScroll) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-shadow');
  } else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-shadow');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  transition: 300ms linear all;
}

.navbar-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar">
    Navigation bar
  </div>
  
  <p>
  Etiam phasellus eget. Adipiscing odio lobortis. Vestibulum ac lacus. Est fermentum penatibus. Eu sit hendrerit. Sed laborum vestibulum. Vivamus faucibus non. Parturient et ut sit turpis nulla fringilla vitae purus penatibus in dolor faucibus tincidunt vestibulum dictumst in lobortis facilisis ac porta. Quisque sed libero sem vestibulum sed donec eros sociis. Sed erat elit elementum etiam lacus montes id adipiscing.

Nec lobortis dolor rutrum commodo proin aliquet taciti varius nec pellentesque in. Molestie pulvinar a sodales sit tortor. In elit laoreet amet id tellus tincidunt risus elit mauris eu odio in consequat lacus amet cursus et ante vestibulum suspendisse elementum commodo sed. Facilisi inceptos nonummy duis nec diam. Arcu quis accumsan morbi id sapien wisi praesent platea. Proin faucibus pretium massa ut facilisi. Velit dignissim pede. Enim dolor donec sed dignissim vel. Libero porta consectetuer. Malesuada viverra nec. Rutrum pellentesque pellentesque vitae per praesent aenean vehicula ligula. Et viverra in. Quis enim in. Sed mi metus. In velit eget. Class hac eros. Ut torquent maecenas. Tellus felis diam nibh sed purus. Vestibulum sit urna lacus ac tortor etiam id mattis. Ea lorem venenatis mauris inceptos sed. Vestibulum aliquip tempor ut lorem lacus feugiat curabitur feugiat mauris nec aliquet duis et amet egestas aptent libero augue massa leo et ac aliquam. Convallis purus accumsan. Aliquam elementum fermentum sit hac est. Sit pellentesque curabitur. Nibh ligula vestibulum. Sed curabitur aenean sint mauris risus condimentum nostra in. Ultricies vulputate id. Cras ornare non. Iaculis mauris praesent. Lobortis rutrum velit. Nulla nibh et. Enim libero pellentesque viverra ac cursus. Ut massa condimentum. Neque lobortis suspendisse sodales eget aenean orci ipsum quaerat. Metus adipiscing montes.

Ut nec sed nulla condimentum quis. Fusce odio bibendum gravida ut eu mauris pede ac. Etiam adipiscing vero gravida amet sunt. Dui vulputate lacus in diam quis. Volutpat nec nam.
  </p>
</div>



</div>
```

Can this be done only with CSS?

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to make the shadow on another div that your also make sticky. The trick is that the new div will be behind the navbar and the sticky behavior will make it appear when needed. The only drawback is that you need to know the height of the navbar to correctly set the `top` value of the new div

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
}

.shadow {
  height: 10px; /* Bigger enough to have the same shadow */
  margin-top: -20px; /* Hide me !*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 18px; /* This is the best value in our case considering the navbar*/
  z-index: 5; /* Lower z-index */
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar">
    Navigation bar
  </div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <p>
    Etiam phasellus eget. Adipiscing odio lobortis. Vestibulum ac lacus. Est fermentum penatibus. Eu sit hendrerit. Sed laborum vestibulum. Vivamus faucibus non. Parturient et ut sit turpis nulla fringilla vitae purus penatibus in dolor faucibus tincidunt
    vestibulum dictumst in lobortis facilisis ac porta. Quisque sed libero sem vestibulum sed donec eros sociis. Sed erat elit elementum etiam lacus montes id adipiscing. Nec lobortis dolor rutrum commodo proin aliquet taciti varius nec pellentesque in.
    Molestie pulvinar a sodales sit tortor. In elit laoreet amet id tellus tincidunt risus elit mauris eu odio in consequat lacus amet cursus et ante vestibulum suspendisse elementum commodo sed. Facilisi inceptos nonummy duis nec diam. Arcu quis accumsan
    morbi id sapien wisi praesent platea. Proin faucibus pretium massa ut facilisi. Velit dignissim pede. Enim dolor donec sed dignissim vel. Libero porta consectetuer. Malesuada viverra nec. Rutrum pellentesque pellentesque vitae per praesent aenean
    vehicula ligula. Et viverra in. Quis enim in. Sed mi metus. In velit eget. Class hac eros. Ut torquent maecenas. Tellus felis diam nibh sed purus. Vestibulum sit urna lacus ac tortor etiam id mattis. Ea lorem venenatis mauris inceptos sed. Vestibulum
    aliquip tempor ut lorem lacus feugiat curabitur feugiat mauris nec aliquet duis et amet egestas aptent libero augue massa leo et ac aliquam. Convallis purus accumsan. Aliquam elementum fermentum sit hac est. Sit pellentesque curabitur. Nibh ligula
    vestibulum. Sed curabitur aenean sint mauris risus condimentum nostra in. Ultricies vulputate id. Cras ornare non. Iaculis mauris praesent. Lobortis rutrum velit. Nulla nibh et. Enim libero pellentesque viverra ac cursus. Ut massa condimentum. Neque
    lobortis suspendisse sodales eget aenean orci ipsum quaerat. Metus adipiscing montes. Ut nec sed nulla condimentum quis. Fusce odio bibendum gravida ut eu mauris pede ac. Etiam adipiscing vero gravida amet sunt. Dui vulputate lacus in diam quis. Volutpat
    nec nam.
  </p>
</div>



</div>
```